# How do I override a dll (without using the winecfg gui) in WINE?

Tags: wine

I broke something in my winecfg. Thus, It won't run any Windows apps in wine anymore. (I cannot afford to mv .wine and reinstall).

How do I override a dll using the command line. I disabled rpcrt4.dll by accident and want to undo it.

When launching winecfg or any windows application like MS Word, Wine prints this error message:

```
err:module:import_dll Library rpcrt4.dll (which is needed by L"C:\\windows\\system32\\explorer.exe") not found
```

Comment: err:module:import_dll Library rpcrt4.dll (which is needed by L"C:\\windows\\system32\\explorer.exe") not found

Answer (score 3):

Firstly, try using `winetricks` on the command-line to revert just your `winecfg` dll settings back to defaults with:

```
winetricks alldlls=default
```

**If** this doesn't solve the problem, you can use WINEDLLOVERRIDES; it is an environmental variable that can be used with `wine` to specify the dll overrides you want (or don't require). As stated on the [manpage](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/precise/en/man1/wine.1.html), WINEDLLOVERRIDES

> Defines  the  override  type  and load order of dlls used in the loading process for any dll. There are currently two types of libraries that can be  loaded  into  a  process'  address  space:  native  windows  dlls
>                 (native),  wine  internal dlls (builtin).  The type may be abbreviated with the first letter of the type (n,
>                 b).  The library may also be disabled (''). Each sequence of orders must be separated by commas.

You can either export the environmental variable, or use `env` and specify the variable to be used with the wine command (if you don't specify a WINEPREFIX it will use the default):

```
env WINEDLLOVERRIDES="rpcrt4=b,n" wine exe_to_run
```

This will specify that the builtin version should be tried, then the native version. If you instead use `"rpcrt4="`, then that dll will remain disabled and `wine` will not run at all.

If you want to export the value to the shell for that session, you can run

```
export WINEDLLOVERRIDES="rpcrt4=b,n"
```

This will not affect the settings in `winecfg`, and they will remain the same. This environmental variable, and many other useful ones available with `wine` are only temporary and merely affect the shell in which they are used, either by exporting the variable or using `env` each time to state the variable and then run `wine` with that variable as it launches your program. You could also specify environmental variables in a bash script that launched your `wine` programs.

For more information, please see `man wine`, the [Ubuntu manpages online](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/precise/en/man1/wine.1.html), and the [useful wine FAQ](http://wiki.winehq.org/FAQ).

Answer (score 0):

I assume you can do it via ~/wine/user.reg, where you should look list of dlls under [Software\Wine\DllOverrides]