# How to restore wine configuration to default?

Tags: wine

I recently messed up with my wine, and now it can't open any application. How do I restore wine to original state and remove everything installed application, just like when it was first installed.

Comment: Rename your `~/.wine` folder to `.wine.backup` and just run `winecfg` to create a new `.wine` default prefix. See also [this question](http://askubuntu.com/questions/218049/how-to-reset-setting-of-wine-avoiding-uninstalling-all-applications-in-it/220758#220758).

Comment: I've done a quick answer with some additional detail that might be helpful.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You should be able to rename `~/.wine` to `~/.wine.backup` and then run the `wine` configuration program from the menu or from the command-line (`winecfg`) and then a new `~/.wine` will be regenerated and you will still have the old `wine` folder and so all your files will remain. You can then decide how to proceed.

Additionally, sometimes the old WINEPREFIX can be fixed by resetting the dll overrides, with `winetricks alldlls=default`, as those overrides can often cause problems, as I discuss [in this answer](https://askubuntu.com/questions/254086/how-do-i-override-a-dll-without-using-the-winecfg-gui-in-wine/279947#279947).

Problems with `wine` can often occur, and that is why I always recommend installing new games or applications in their own WINEPREFIX, as I discuss here:

- [How to reset setting of Wine, avoiding uninstalling all applications in it?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/218049/how-to-reset-setting-of-wine-avoiding-uninstalling-all-applications-in-it/220758#220758)